# how to open an external link from a webView in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have an app in swift and inside it I have a webview that calls my page, on my page I have a button to log in with google, backend firebsae, and the method I use is signInWithPopup and I want to open the popup but from safari

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "")
        let request = NSURLRequest (url:url as! URL)
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        SVProgressHUD.show()

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 0.5)
        }else{
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
        estadoAutorizacion()

    }
```

Comment: you may need to enable `allowArbitraryLoads` within your `info.plist` file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle/open external links from safari, you need to implement

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
  decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
  decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Make your view controller confirm to `WKNavigationDelegate` and assign your controller to `navigationDelegate` property of webView